# Swift: Project Directory Write Access from UITests

Tags: swift, xcode, nsfilemanager, xcode-ui-testing

I've converted my UITests from ObjC to Swift.

My UITests would take screenshots and save them in the project directory and it worked great!

Now, the Swift version can't write to the directory anymore. Here is the code:

```
let thisFileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: #file, isDirectory: false)
let baseProjUrl = thisFileUrl.deletingLastPathComponent().deletingLastPathComponent()
let screenshotUrl = baseProjUrl.appendingPathComponent("Screenshots").appendingPathComponent(dateString)
let screenshotPath = screenshotUrl.absoluteString
let isWritable = FileManager.default.isWritableFile(atPath: screenshotUrl.deletingLastPathComponent().absoluteString)
```

and the isWritableFile is false!

I've executed:

```
chmod -R 777 Screenshots
```

With no luck :(

I looked through build settings, and the only thing I found that might impact this is the "Install Permissions" which is set to "u+w,go-w,a+rX", and I have no idea if modifying this would help, or what to set it to.

Thanks for any help!